# Excel object for range format

Tags: excel, vba

I am searching for a way to apply to a destination Excel range the same format of a source range.

Making use of `Copy()` and `PasteSpecial()` methods doesn't work because I need to use it inside `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` and the `PasteSpecial()` method changes self the selection.

**The question is:**

Is there an Excel object which can store the whole set of format features of a single cell or range in order to retrieve them later?

Comment: More exactly I need some method like "doFormatCopy(ByRef sourceRange.Interior, ByRef destinationRange.Interior)" without Copy-PasteSpecial calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this,

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
Application.EnableEvents = 0

    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode=False
    Target.Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
Application.EnableEvents = 1
```

But, personally prefer to set the formats in the destination cells to how I want them, it is much easier to follow what you are doing to the sheet.

Comment: Is a good solution to have a preset of a format already but this will be known only at runtime. The end-user expects to have in a designated range (more exactly, in a set of ranges) determined by the value of the last edited cell (that is, the current selection) the same format (everything, including the fill-effects, with gradient color etc) defined in a "template" cell he set by his own. So, everything is decided at runtime.

Comment: @ciutacu, well that is exactly what this does, the user decides what what formats will be copied by them changing the source cells, then when copied, this will copy those formats.

Comment: It does, but cannot be used inside "Worksheet_SelectionChange()" event-procedure (stored in "Worksheet") because "PasteSpecial()" changes the selection too.

Comment: @ciutacu, of coarse you can use it. see edited code.

Comment: @ciutacu, And if this solves your question ,please remember to UV and mark as solved.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem and is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ciutacu, Glad I could help. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You've not given us a lot to go on as far as where the source and destination cells are in relation to the SelectionChange Target cell.

There's probably a much better solution given all the facts, but this code copies the Bold & NumberFormat from the cell to the right of Target to the Target cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        .Font.Bold = .Offset(, 1).Font.Bold
        .NumberFormat = .Offset(, 1).NumberFormat
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is a good idea to let every format asset to be copied from source to destination through assignment operator but there are a lot of them and the program must also be very, very fast as is intended to run in 'Worksheet_SelectionChange()' event-proc. In addition, the fill-effects cannot be copied this way.